# 403 Forbidden error with Google URL shortener API when accessing public data

Tags: google-contacts-api, google-url-shortener

I'm trying to [expand a public short url](https://developers.google.com/url-shortener/v1/getting_started#expa) using the Google URL Shortener API. The Google URL Shortener API is discontinued from March 30th as described in this [blog post](https://developers.googleblog.com/2018/03/transitioning-google-url-shortener.html). Instead I should be using Firebase Dynamic Links but I can't find any docs on expanding URLs with FDL.

I'm only accessing public data so I have been using the shortener URL api with only an API key:

```sh
curl https://www.googleapis.com/urlshortener/v1/url\?shortUrl\=https://goo.gl/maps/JtZ2Yq19vJP2\&key\=MY_API_KEY
```

I always get the following response:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "forbidden",
    "message": "Forbidden"
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Forbidden"
 }
}
```

When using the API explorer I'm getting the same response so I'm assuming it's because the API is being discontinued so how can I use Firebase Dynamic Links to do the same?

Answer (score 0):

I am also had same issue since last week. I searched for solution but the reason is Google is shutting down its goo.gl URL shortening service.

https://www.engadget.com/2018/03/30/google-shutting-down-goo-gl-url-shortening-service/